# How to create a carousel pattern

Tags: android

I'd like to implement the following swipe pattern: http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/carousel

I've been struggling with this during the past 3 days. Can anyone please help me achieve that and attach some code?

Comment: Refer this link for making a gallery http://www.programr.com/Android/Android_3D_Carousel

Comment: Thank you very much but how can i set the position of the first and last images?

Comment: in CarouselAdapter.java class having the position declarations

Comment: In this years Google I/O (2019) there was a session about the new MotionLayout where they showed an approach to implement such a carousel view quite easily.